# Web addin dialog box in powerpoint: centering and inserting web browser emulation

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, add-in, office-addins

**Operation system**: Windows 10

**MS Office version**: 2019 64-bit

I am trying to create an `MS Office web add-in` which allows me to place different html pages to different slides. While reading different parts of the MS documentation and web-searching, I could not understand how to:

1. Center the so-called `Taskpane` in the center of a slide after start
2. Insert a `web object` with an option to show some `website content` (including `js`) *WITHOUT* errors connected to MS Office safety

A good example is a `Plotly D3.JS Charts`. I try to do practically the same but with support of loading local `html` files.

[image]

**UPD**: I know about `LiveWeb`, `LiveSlides` and other solutions. However, they have their own security problems - I have to correct `regit`. Therefore, please, do not propose them.

Comment: The CustomTaskPane object is intended for controls with which the user interacts, similar to the Format Object task pane. You wouldn't normally place this in the center of a slide. Have you looked at Shyam Pillai's LiveWeb add-in? It seems to already do what you're trying to program. http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm

Comment: @JohnKorchok, no, there is a strong point to put it into the center. I saw the `LiveWeb` add-in. There is a problem with it - the security error. Moreover, it is a `VSTO` add-in, not `Office.js` one. `Plotly D3.JS` does not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The task pane in an Office Web Add-in always opens to the side of the Office application window. You cannot configure it to open in the center of the document. Also, you cannot have separate task panes for each slide.

Comment: Well then how does the `Plotly D3.JS` web add-in work? I am sure there should be a way.

Comment: Would a [content add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#create-new-objects-in-office-documents) work for you?

Comment: I think yes, but I do not understand what is the difference between creating a `Task Pane` with its functionality and a `content add-in`. I would be very grateful if you provide me an example of how to use it...

Comment: There's more information at [Content Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins). I found this by searching for `office content add-in`. It was the top result.

Comment: Rick, thank you for a link! However, I saw it before while googling. My main problem is that I can't understand how to place a `content add in pane` in the center. There is no example in the official documentation, that is why I asked there to provide it.

Comment: Another problem - I do not understand how to make this window read a HTML file at my local computer. I saw methods to put text, image but there is no method to put HTML, load internet page, etc... If you know this method, could you please provide a code example or at least write its name here?

Comment: Samples of content add-ins are: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Content-Add-in-Humongous-Insurance and https://github.com/OfficeDev/Add-in-Content-Sample

Comment: Also, how would you do what you are trying to do from the Insert ribbon in PowerPoint? If you cannot do it in the PowerPoint UI, then you cannot do it programmatically either.

Comment: Thank you again! I tried to use `getSelectedDataAsync` method with `html` but there was no effect. I tried to replace `body` of `pane` but it also did not work. Which method or object type should I use to place some html site into `PowerPoint` window / `task pane`?

Comment: I know definitely that I can do it becasue there is a `Plotly D3.JS` add in which works in `PowerPoint` and gives me result that I want (except that I can't load a custom `html page` from my local cumputer -> the thing I want to do as a result).

Comment: Plotly D3.JS is a Content Add-in. Like all Content Add-ins, it is a web application hosted in a web control. If you want another site to appear in the web control, I suggest that you host an iframe in the web application. Set the src property of the iframe to the URL of the site that you want to appear. This is what the Plotly D3.JS add-in does. Consider installing it, running it, and then inspecting it in either [Edge Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj) if your Windows 10 is v. 1903, or with F12 tools, if Win 10 is before 1903.